# How to form a REST response from Map<String, Map<Object, Long>>?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, dictionary, web

so I am stuck for real now (surprise, surprise), hopefully someone can actually help me.

Let me explain my problem:

Entities

```
public class Candidate {

@Id
@Column(unique = true)
private int number;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String agenda;
```

...

```
public class Voter {

@Id
@Column(unique = true)
private int ssn;
@Column
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Region region;
```

...

```
public class Vote {

@Id
@Column(unique = true)
@GeneratedValue
private int ballotId;
@OneToOne
private Voter voter;
@ManyToOne
private Candidate candidate;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Issue issue;
private Date createdOn;
```

...

One of the requirements is to return an overall distribution of votes amongst candidates, which looks like

```
[
 {
    "numberOfVotes": 211,
    "candidate": {
        "name": "Name Surname",
        "identifier": 2
    }
 },
 {
    "numberOfVotes": 109,
    "candidate": {
        "name": "Name Surname",
        "identifier": 1
    }
 },
```

...

And I achieve this by these steps:
from my service class i return:

```
return Map<Candidate, Long> votesPerCandidates = voteRepository.findAll().stream().collect(groupingBy(Vote::getCandidate, counting()));
```

this response then gets mapped to DTO in controller class like this:

```
List<VoteDto> votesPerCandidate = new ArrayList<>();
    voteService.getVotesPerCandidate().forEach((candidate, numberOfVotes) -> votesPerCandidate.add(new VoteDto(new CandidateDto(candidate), numberOfVotes)));
    return votesPerCandidate;
```

Do you think this part can be improved, if yes then how, what am I doing wrong?

and now my actual struggle comes with this requirement:
I need to return a voting result distribution amongst different regions, which should look like that:

```
[
{
    "identifier": "Alaska",
    "votes": [
        {
            "numberOfVotes": 91,
            "candidate": {
                "name": "Person1 person1",
                "identifier": 2
            }
        },
        {
            "numberOfVotes": 43,
            "candidate": {
                "name": "Person2 person2",
                "identifier": 1
            }
        },
    ]
},
{
    "identifier": "Nebraska",
    "votes": [
        {
            "numberOfVotes": 55,
            "candidate": {
                "name": "Person1 person1",
                "identifier": 2
            }
        },
        {
            "numberOfVotes": 109,
            "candidate": {
                "name": "Person2 person2",
                "identifier": 1
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

]

what I did in my service class is :

```
return Map<String, Map<Candidate, Long>> votesPerRegion = voteRepository.findAll().stream().collect(groupingBy((Vote vote) ->
        vote.getVoter().getRegion().name(), groupingBy(Vote::getCandidate, counting())));
```

then in controller lass I have lost my faith on how to solve it. Looping over map within the map, does not give desired outcome and i fail to fill my DTO object:

```
public class RegionDto {

private String region;
private List<VoteDto> votes;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the result for distribution of the votes by region may be returned as list of `RegionDto`:

```
// assumed implementation of VoteDto using Lombok
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
static class VoteDto {
    private CandidateDto candidate;
    private long numberOfVotes;
}

//...
List<RegionDto> result = votes.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(v -> v.voter.getRegion().getName(),
                        Collectors.groupingBy(v -> v.candidate, Collectors.counting())))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .map(e -> new RegionDto(e.getKey(),       // get region name
                        e.getValue().entrySet().stream()  // build a list of VoteDto
                                .map(v -> new VoteDto(
                                    new CandidateDto(v.getKey()), v.getValue()))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Similar implementation may be used for the previous case (but is is fine):

```
List<VoteDto> voteStats = votes.stream()
                               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                                   Vote::getCandidate, Collectors.counting()))
                               .entrySet().stream()
                               .map(e -> new VoteDto(
                                   new CandidateDto(e.getKey()), e.getValue()))
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple intuitive way to construct the response list is:

```
    List<RegionDTO> regionDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
    votesPerRegion.forEach((identifier,candidateToVoteMap) -> {
      RegionDTO regionDTO = new RegionDTO();
      regionDTO.setIdentifier(identifier);
      List<VoteDTO> voteDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
      candidateToVoteMap.forEach((candidate, numberOfVotes) -> {
        VoteDTO voteDTO = new VoteDTO();
        voteDTO.setCandidate(candidate);
        voteDTO.setNumberOfVotes(numberOfVotes);
        voteDTOList.add(voteDTO);
      });
      regionDTO.setVotes(voteDTOList);
      regionDTOList.add(regionDTO);
    });
```

This is without using stream API.

Next, regarding your other question:

Do you think this part can be improved, if yes then how, what am I doing wrong?

You arent wrong but it can be improved. You are doing the whole grouping at java layer. Instead you can use a native query/ JPQL and do aggregation at db layer and get the desired result. An example of JPQL aggregation can be found [here](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/group) and at many other place.